# When projection of $a$ onto $b$ is equal to projection of $ b$ onto $a$

Tags: linear-algebra

Having a lot of trouble with my Linear Algebra course and am stuck on this question.

"Suppose $a$ and $b$ are non-zero vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ with the property that proj $a$ onto $b$ = proj $b$ onto $a$. What can you conclude about $a$
and $b$ $?$ Justify by describing the implied geometry and also by providing an
algebraic calculation that shows your intuition is correct."

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the relation between b and the projection of a onto b?

Comment: Consider parallel and orthogonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: projecting a vector onto $\bf v$ yields a vector parallel to $\bf v$.

Comment: Something I didn't consider! So proj(a on b) is parallel to b and proj(b on a) is parallel to a. Therefore since proj(a on b) = proj(b on a), a and b must be parallel to the same vector and hence a is parallel to b....?

Comment: @Bob : Don't forget the special case where the vectors are orthogonal and the projections are $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If we are just considering the case that the magnitudes must be the same, then a and b can be any vectors in Real space.

However, if a . b = b . a (they result in the same vector), then they have to be on the same line. If they are not, there is some angle theta by which the two-dot products are separated. Two lines of the same magnitude, starting from the same point, and separated by an angle of 0 are the same.